# Applying AddMethod() to validation function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am new to  jquery, I am trying to validate a group of checkboxes[] 
using the [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). After searching the internet I came across 
this AddMethod( ) which seems to resolve the issue of checkboxes, but I 
can not find any piece of code that explains how to apply the new method name 
to the validate().

Here is my code of what I am trying to achieve

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.validator.addMethod('minchecked',function(value, element) {
          return $(element).filter(':checked').length >= 1;
}, 'please make a selection');

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#onlinesurvey").validate({
      rules: {
         <!== do not know how apply the new method if it does go here ==>
      }
    });
});
</script>

<html>
<body>
<form id="onlinesurvey">
<fieldset id="stageone">
<label for="q1a"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" id="q1a" value="Blue Square Casino" />Blue Square Casino</label>
<label for="q1b"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" id="q1b" value="Paddy Power" />Paddy Power</label>
<label for="q1c"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" id="q1c" value="Sky Vegas" />Sky Vegas</label>
<label for="q1d"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" id="q1d" value="Virgin Casino" />Virgin Casino</label>
<label for="q1e"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" id="q1e" value="Other(s)" />Other(s)</label>
<label for="q1[]" class="error">Please make a selection</label>
</div>  
<input type="button" value="next" class="next" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should enter an answer with your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#onlinesurvey").validate({
  rules: {
     minchecked: true
  }
});
```

Comment: I applied that piece of code but it still didn't work - my confusion is the addMethod "minchecked" applied to every checkbox inn that form